# Controlling JTree expansion delay on drag & drop

Tags: java, swing

Our system currently allows users to drag & drop on a JTree. When the user hovers over a node in the tree we have written code to expand the tree node. However, the speed of java and modern computers being what they are the nodes tend to expand extremely fast. If a user drags over many nodes in the tree very quickly all the nodes expand.

What we need is some delay before the tree node expansion occurs, maybe a second or two. To complicate matters if the user does not stay hovered over a node for the allotted delay the node should not expand.

What would be the best way of implementing this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) that will execute a task to expand the node after a given delay.  You can also cancel pending tasks when the user moves over a new node.

Ex:

```
public class ReScheduler {
  private ScheduledFuture<?> currentTask = null;
  private static final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
  public void schedule(Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit units) {
    if (currentTask != null) {
       currentTask.cancel();
       currentTask = null;
    }
    currentTask = executor.schedule(command, delay, units);
  }
}
```

In your client code, on the Swing UI thread, with an existing instance of ReScheduler you would do the following whenever a new node is hovered over:

```
myRescheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(task to expand the node in the tree!);
   }
}, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

For best practice, you should provide a thread factory to "Executors.newScheduledThreadPool" that will name the threads that are created.  Something like a [NamedThreadFactory](http://code.google.com/p/tantalizing-eats/source/browse/src/com/tantaman/eats/tools/concurrent/NamedThreadFactory.java).

Doing what StanislavL suggested would actually be a little more straightfroward.  Whenever you hover over a component, schedule a task that will expand that component.  When the task kicks off, have it check to see if the user is still hovering over the component that casued the task to be scheduled.

```
    public void hovered() {
      final Component node = node currently hovered over; // node is the component
// that is causing the task to be scheduled
      executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          // see if the node that the mouse is over now is the same node it was over 2 seconds ago
          if (getComponentUnderMouse() == node) {
            expand(node); // do this on the EDT
          } else {
            // do nothing because we are over some other node
          }
        }
      }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Comment: I would say it will open the same nodes after 2 seconds.

Comment: It could open a node after you mouse out of the component.

Answer (score 1):

When mouse is over a node you can start Timer with desired delay. When Timer action is invoked just check whether mouse is still over the same node. If yes expand it if not just do nothing.

Comment: Some more detail in your answer would be helpful. mlaw's answer is using a scheduler and another thread to get the timer behavior you mention. What would you do differently from that?

Comment: @BenjaminLinus StanislavL's solution is a little more straightforward. You would hover over the component then: ` final Component originatingComponent = origComp; executor.schedule(new Runnable() { public void run() { if mouse is over the originatingComponent, expand. else, do nothing. } }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);